# pyside2 - remove border of Qbutton

Tags: pyside2

i have a error that when i touch my touch screen then the buttons will have border.

I added "border-radius" in qss file.But this don't help.

-video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3e5ArF6GIk) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3e5ArF6GIk

- [remove yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MeAC.png)
- [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhPZw.png)

how can i remove it?

- Button QSS

```
QPushButton{
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font: bold italic;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
QPushButton#btn_checkout{
    text-align: right;
}

QPushButton:checked,
QPushButton:pressed {
    border-color: 3px blue;
    background-color: #d0d67c;
    color: #0000FF;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

QPushButton:disabled{
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Please provide *real* screenshots, not photos of the screen.

Comment: In [this thread](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65773-Round-QPushButton) it tells that if your `border-radius` property is too big, it will not even render with rounded border. (Tested on PySide2, and the buttons' borders were rectangular, not rounded with a `border-radius: 30px`). By setting it to a lower value, such as `18px` fixed for me, and no yellow borders were displayed when pressing / toggling the button.